# How to execute a Runtime command in a jar file from a USB drive?

Tags: java, command-line, runtime, wsh

My Java app runs a command like this :

```
String Command="C:\A_Test\Dir_PC_Customizer\Chinese_English_Dictionary_PinItem.cmd";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(Command);
```

I packaged it into a Jar file and it runs fine from C:/ drive.
But after I copied it into a USB key-chain drive, it won't run.

And my Chinese_English_Dictionary_PinItem.cmd file is :

```
@echo off
set ITEM=
set TASKBAR=

set ITEM=/item:"C:\A_Test\Dir_Chinese_English_Dictionary\Chinese_English_Dictionary.exe"
set TASKBAR=/taskbar

echo on
:: Pin to Taskbar
cscript //nologo PinItem.wsf %ITEM% %TASKBAR%
```

When it's run from C:/, the output looks like this :

```
Command = C:\A_Test\Dir_PC_Customizer\Chinese_English_Dictionary_PinItem.cmd
Result : 
Executing : C:\A_Test\Dir_PC_Customizer\Chinese_English_Dictionary_PinItem.cmd

C:\Dir_PC_Customizer>cscript //nologo PinItem.wsf /item:"C:\A_Test\Dir_Chinese_English_Dictionary\Chinese_English_Dictionary.exe" /taskbar 
Property item is now = C:\A_Test\Dir_Chinese_English_Dictionary\Chinese_English_Dictionary.exe
Property taskbar is now = 
Microsoft Deployment Toolkit version: 6.1.2373.0
------------ Initialization PinItem -------------
The /item switch specified with value: C:\A_Test\Dir_Chinese_English_Dictionary\Chinese_English_Dictionary.exe
The /taskbar switch was specified.
Function-GetSpecialFolder: Cannot determine special folder for CSIDL_PROFILES
Item "C:\A_Test\Dir_Chinese_English_Dictionary\Chinese_English_Dictionary.exe" pinned successfully
------------ Departing PinItem -------------
PinItem processing completed successfully.
```

But when it's run from USB drive, the output looks like this :

```
Executing : C:\A_Test\Dir_PC_Customizer\Chinese_English_Dictionary_PinItem.cmd

F:\Dir_PC_Customizer\dist>cscript //nologo PinItem.wsf /item:"C:\A_Test\Dir_Chinese_English_Dictionary\Chinese_English_Dictionary.exe" /taskbar 
Input Error: Can not find script file "F:\Dir_PC_Customizer\dist\PinItem.wsf".
```

Note : they are executing the same file :

`C:\A_Test\Dir_PC_Customizer\Chinese_English_Dictionary_PinItem.cmd`

they are just executing from C:/ or from F:/

What's obvious is : when run from C:/ , it's : C:\Dir_PC_Customizer>cscript

When run from F:/ , it's F:\Dir_PC_Customizer\dist>cscript

And the error message says : "F:\Dir_PC_Customizer\dist\PinItem.wsf" not found, because PinItem.wsf and other few files are in : F:\Dir_PC_Customizer [ and in C:\A_Test\Dir_PC_Customizer ] , not in dist.

My question is : if I want to make it be able to run from any drive : C:/, F:/ or G:/, what should I do ?

I guess one way to do it is to tell it "although I'm running in "F:\Dir_PC_Customizer\dist", but pretend I'm running from "C:\A_Test\Dir_PC_Customizer", but how to tell it to switch directory ? That's the key.

Comment: Is Chinese_English_Dictionary_PinItem.cmd distributed inside same folder as your jar?

Comment: It's not inside the Jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, when the app runs, copy the extra few files from parent directory to the current directory so they will be found.